# How to Check a table1 field depending on a table2 field? Check constraints don't accept subqueries

Tags: sql, constraints

Let me wish you a good day, even if I am having a hard time with the check constraint.
Want I want to do is check if the value of field1 is less than the value in the field2 of another table. I have tried this

```
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cote]
 ADD CONSTRAINT CoteMarksLessThanTestMax 
 CHECK(Marks<=(select sum(t.Max) from Test as t WHERE TestID=IdTest) )
```

This returns an error saying : subqueries are not allowed in this context. How can I do it otherwise? I mean without using the `check` constraint?

**COTE** (CoteID,IdTest,Marks)

**TEST** (TestID,Max)

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger.

**References**:

1. [BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER on Tech on the Net](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/before_insert.php)
2. [Using Triggers on Oracle® Database PL/SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#LNPLS020)